# Assign Integer value to each button in Button Array in Unity

Tags: arrays, user-interface, for-loop, unity-game-engine, button

Is there a way to assign an integer value based on the Button Text to each UI button in an array and then check for that value OnClick() for valid move based on the value assigned ?

basically

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
    {
        buttons[i].interactable = true;
        buttons[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = null;
        // some code here to assign an integer value to each button in the 
        // array.  int boardSquareValue; is in a separate script named Value 
        // attached to each button object;


    }
```

Each Buttons Text child object has the Button's value as the text.  If I can convert that to a usable int that would be great too and could eliminate the use of a external script?

There is a script attached to each button gameobject named Value with a single public in variable called boardSquareValue.

Kind of a tictactoe thing, only each square has a value, and conditions for valid moves will be based on those integer values on a much larger board.

Ive tried everything I can think of.

In summary, I'd like to click on a square, have a piece become active (this is done), check the value of that square, and if the value is correct (integer value from 0 through 4) say Yes this move is valid, or No this move isn't valid.  I just cant get the value assigned to the darn button.

EDIT:

Each number shown is the value of the square.  A player cannot place a piece in a square with a value less than their previous square's value.  I have to assign that value as an int in some way or another.  The for loop makes the buttons interactable and sets the player piece sprites to null.   I need it to set the integer value of each square as well if possible.

[Gameboard and Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuXX6.png)

Script:

```
public void GameSetup()
{
    whosTurnIsIt = 0;
    turnCount = 0;
    turnIcons[0].SetActive(true);
    turnIcons[1].SetActive(false);
    for (int i = 0; i < playAreaSquares.Length; i++)
    {
        playAreaSquares[i].interactable = true;
        playAreaSquares[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = null;
        boardSquareValue = playAreaSquares[i].GetComponent<Value>().boardSquareValue;
        Debug.Log(playAreaSquares[i].GetComponent<Value>().boardSquareValue);
    }








}

public void SetValueOfSquare()
{
    //Debug.Log("This square's value is: " + squareValue);
    //squareValue = gameObject.GetComponent<Value>().boardSquareValue;

}

public void PlaySquareButton(int WhichNumber)
 {
    playAreaSquares[WhichNumber].image.sprite = playIcons[whosTurnIsIt];
    playAreaSquares[WhichNumber].interactable = false;
    // int.TryParse(playAreaSquares[WhichNumber]., out boardSquareValueOther.boardSquareValue);
    boardSquareValue = playAreaSquares[WhichNumber].GetComponent<Value>().boardSquareValue;


    if (whosTurnIsIt == 0)
    {
        whosTurnIsIt = 1;
        turnIcons[0].SetActive(false);
        turnIcons[1].SetActive(true);
        Debug.Log(boardSquareValue);
        lastPlayedSquareValueX = boardSquareValue;

    }
    else
    {
        whosTurnIsIt = 0;
        turnIcons[0].SetActive(true);
        turnIcons[1].SetActive(false);
        Debug.Log(boardSquareValueOther.boardSquareValue);
        lastPlayedSquareValueO = boardSquareValue;
    }

 }
```

}

Its a mess right now cause I'm trying so many different things to make this work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. You have a grid similar to a chess board? You want to get the grid cell location on click?

Comment: See edit.  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You might want `int i = int.Parse("123");`

Comment: It sees the value of the first button then I get the Null Reference exception shown in the image.

Comment: On your screen shot I can see only 1 square element in Game Controller Squares. What is the value of `playAreaSquares.Length`?

Comment: I edited the screenshot, I uploaded the wrong one.  The int parse may have worked, I'm getting zero values on some squares but I'm cleaning up the code as its all over the place.  Will update

Comment: Also consider using `transform.GetSiblingIndex()`. It's a zero-based index.

Comment: Would you like to have a Teamviewer session? Seems to become an interesting game. :)

Comment: I got it.  Had too many things going on.  Forgot removed value script from a few game objects during testing.  FACEPALM.  Thanks everyone